# Scheduled methods in Multimodule Spring Boot Gradle project are not getting executed

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, multi-module, spring-scheduled, gradle-multi-project-build

I have created a multimodule Springboot gradle project and the project structure is as below. When I run the MultimoduleApplication.class, the scheduled method in the child module is not getting executed at all.

|
--src
|
--com.test.multimodule(package)
|
--MultimoduleApplication(Class with Main method and with @SpringBootApplication)
--build.gradle (added dependency for child module)
--settings.gradle (included the child module)
child module
|
--src
|
--com.test.child(package)
|
--Child Application(Class with Main method and with @SpringBootApplication)
--ScheduleClass(Class with a @Scheduled method)
--resources
|
--application.properties

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynAFf.png)

Schedule method class from the child module.

```
package com.test.child;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.List;

@Component
public class ScheduleClass {

    @Value("${custom.property1}")
    private String customString;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000, initialDelay = 10000)
    public void publishEventStoreRecords()
    {
            System.out.println("Testing " + customString);

    }

}
```

Main class from the root project that I am running

```
package com.test.multimodule;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.test")
public class MultimoduleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MultimoduleApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

root project's build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.3'
}

group = 'com.test'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
     annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    implementation project(':child')
}
```

```
rootProject.name = 'multimodule'
include 'child'
```

I tried adding @ComponentScan on the rootproject's Main class and also made sure to add @Component annotation on the scheduled methods's class in child module.

I am expecting the schedmethod in the child module to execute automatically at the scheduled intervals after I ran the rootproject's Main class(MultimoduleApplication)